# Is it possible to get values to another sheet from a column, but only on the row that i want, depending on another column update?

Tags: google-sheets

I don't really know how to explain it, but i really need some help here.

So, right now, i have a sheet that is recieving values from a form. Those values are being sorted and sent to another sheet, which is then filtered. Now, the thing is, the values of the form are inserted horizontally and then filtered vertically, and since this file is updated daily, i have an index function to update the date (time) in Sheet 2, and the products quantity. The main problem is that when i fill the form in the next day, the sheet that sorts the values will show the values from the previous day (the row above), if the field stays blank in the most recent form entry and i wanted to make like some sort of fuction that only shows the values from the row (day) that updated (new form response).

I'll attach here some screenshots of what i have right now, and the fuctions that I'm using:

Forms table:

[image]

Filtering table (as you can see, the product bacon, for example, is showing up in 18th january, which is wrong):

[image]

The code to get the most recent form entry:

```
=INDEX('Respostas do Formulário 1'!B2:B,MATCH(143^143,'Respostas do Formulário 1'!B2:B))
```

Comment: Please rework title and tags to show this question is about Google-Sheets (according to your screenshots) and not Excel.

Comment: Edit: I think i managed to solve it by using this formula: `=INDEX('Respostas do Formulário 1'!M:M,MATCH(MAX('Respostas do Formulário 1'!B:B),'Respostas do Formulário 1'!B:B,0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within sheets I've done a minimalistic setup as yours and this formula would go into `cell A3`

if you have to retrieve the whole list of products + numbers for specified date in `cell B1`

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Respostas do Formulário 1'!C1:1000,('Respostas do Formulário 1'!B:B=B1)+(ROW('Respostas do Formulário 1'!B:B)=1)))
```

[image]

-

if you have to retrieve only the products with >0 quantity then use:

```
=LAMBDA(ax,FILTER(ax,INDEX(ax,,2)<>""))(TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Respostas do Formulário 1'!C1:1000,('Respostas do Formulário 1'!B:B=B1)+(ROW('Respostas do Formulário 1'!B:B)=1))))
```

[image]